# Select last input with a value greater than zero jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with a bunch of inputs set with value zero like

`<input type="text" name="qty" size="4" autocomplete="off" class="form-control quantity_wanted text" value="0">`

The user then types in quantities of products they want. I want to select the last input where they entered a quantity.   I was able to do something similar with checkboxes like this.

`$('.product-checkbox:checkbox:checked:last')`

But how can I put in a condition for an input box to select the last input with value greater than zero? Thanks.

Comment: [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get inputs with value greater than 0. [`last`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) to get the last one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `:not()` and the Attribute Selector `[attribute]`

```
:not([value='0'])
```

#### JavaScript example

```js
let qtyGT0 = [...document.querySelectorAll(".qty:not([value='0'])")].reverse()[0];

// Just to test
if (qtyGT0) qtyGT0.classList.add("red");
```

```css
.red{ background:red; }
```

```html
<input class="qty" value="0">
<input class="qty" value="1">
<input class="qty" value="1">
<input class="qty" value="0">
```

---

#### Another JavaScript example

in pure JavaScript **ES6** it would look like

```js
let qtyGT0 = [...document.querySelectorAll(".qty")].filter( el => el.value > 0 ).pop();

// Just to test
if (qtyGT0) qtyGT0.classList.add("red");
```

```css
.red{ background:red; }
```

```html
<input class="qty" value="0">
<input class="qty" value="1">
<input class="qty" value="1">
<input class="qty" value="0">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

---

#### jQuery:

```js
var $qtyGT0 = $(".qty").filter((i, el) => el.value > 0 ).last();

// Just to test
$qtyGT0.addClass("red");
```

```css
.red{ background:red; }
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="qty" value="0">
<input class="qty" value="1">
<input class="qty" value="1">
<input class="qty" value="0">
```

http://api.jquery.com/filter/
https://api.jquery.com/last/

Answer (score 2):

A pure JavaScript answer is that you would just iterate them in reverse and stop at the first one you find.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

for(var len = inputs.length-1; len >=0; len--){
  if(inputs[len].value > 0){
     console.log(inputs[len].name);
     inputs[len].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
     break;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="qty" size="4" autocomplete="off" class="form-control quantity_wanted text" value="1">
<input type="text" name="qty2" size="4" autocomplete="off" class="form-control quantity_wanted text" value="2">
<input type="text" name="qty3" size="4" autocomplete="off" class="form-control quantity_wanted text" value="3">
<input type="text" name="qty4" size="4" autocomplete="off" class="form-control quantity_wanted text" value="0">
```